# How to add a CaptchaField() in a Crispy Form in Django?

Tags: python, django

I'm using the package `django-simple-captcha` in my Django app.

The [documentation](http://django-simple-captcha.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage.html) states that to add the captcha field in a form, all you need to do is

```
from django import forms
from captcha.fields import CaptchaField

class CaptchaTestForm(forms.Form):
    myfield = AnyOtherField()
    captcha = CaptchaField()
```

However, how do I use such a field, if my form is a crispy form, which is as follows -

```
class SignupForm(authtoolsforms.UserCreationForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SignupForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.fields["email"].widget.input_type = "email"

        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Field('email', placeholder="Enter Email", autofocus=""),
            Field('name', placeholder="Enter Full Name"),
            Field('password1', placeholder="Enter Password"),
            Field('password2', placeholder="Re-enter Password"),
            Field('gender', placeholder="Gender"),
            Submit('sign_up', 'Sign up', css_class="btn-warning"),
            )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class SignupForm(authtoolsforms.UserCreationForm):
    captcha = CaptchaField()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SignupForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.fields["email"].widget.input_type = "email"

        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Field('email', placeholder="Enter Email", autofocus=""),
            Field('name', placeholder="Enter Full Name"),
            Field('password1', placeholder="Enter Password"),
            Field('password2', placeholder="Re-enter Password"),
            Field('gender', placeholder="Gender"),
            Field('captcha ', placeholder="Enter captcha"),
            Submit('sign_up', 'Sign up', css_class="btn-warning"),
            )
```